# How to change a text in JSON that has quotes in it?

Tags: python, json, file-read

The following code works on python without any issue. It opens the JSON file, and replace all `bananas` to `apples`:

```
import json

replacements = "banana" : "apple"

with open(mycodepath, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
for old, new in replacements.items():
    data = data.replace(old, new)
```

However, I want to replace `"ArmReoriented", "visible": true` with `"ArmReoriented", "visible": false,`

I tried using triple quotes, but it does not work.

```
replacements = """ArmReoriented", "visible": true""" : """ArmReoriented", "visible": false,"""
```

How I replace a text containing quotes on JSON using Python?

Comment: Never manipulate raw JSON text! You wrote `import json` but then you never use it!

Comment: You can include the double quotes in the strings you pass `replace()` by specifying them like this: `'"banana"'` and `'"apple"'`.

Comment: Can you give us more of your JSON document, so we know what key the value `ArmReoriented` is associated with?

Comment: @Gustavo, ...personally, I wouldn't use Python for this job. It's a one-liner in jq. Assuming that `ArmReoriented` is the value associated with a key `LastEvent` (just to pick something at random): `jq 'walk(if type == "object" and .["LastEvent"] == "ArmReoriented" and .["visible"] == true then .["visible"]=false else . end)'` will do the trick.

Comment: Note that JSON does not guarantee a serialization order! Just because one time you write your file it says `{"A": "B", "C": "D"}` doesn't mean it won't be `{"C": "D", "A": "B"}` the next time, so any code that assumes that `"B"` will always come before `"C"` is buggy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Im a total beginner in programming. I just my python code to change the JSON code from a template, which then I upload the code as a whole to create the page. I dont see why manupulation the raw JSON text is so bad because apparently is just a text document before I upload.

Comment: @Gustavo because dictionary keys are unordered and depending on the JSON serializer, the order might change and break your code. Not to mention whitespace and indentation. It's a bad practice because it is very fragile. Plus, it's 10x easier to parse the JSON, modify it, then serialize it back out to text.

Comment: @Gustavo, ...just to add some flavor to what Gillespie was saying -- once upon a time I worked for a web startup, and one of the things that made a huge amount of otherwise-unnecessary work was customers who used the kind of technique you're showing here, "parsing" JSON content as strings -- because when we changed the API in ways that wouldn't have broken a real, compliant parser, it *did* break their code, so they'd always be complaining when some new feature we add broke their hand-built workflows.

Comment: @Gustavo, ...to give you an example, let's say that one day, instead of the JSON saying `{"action": "ArmReoriented", "visible": true}` it says `{"action": "ArmReoriented", "timestamp": "2019-01-01T15:36:01", "visible": true}`. That addition of a `timestamp` field would make no difference a *compliant* parser, but suddenly "visible" no longer comes right after `"ArmReoriented"`, so it would break the logic you're talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Using """ is basically a ***comment*** or a ***doc-string*** and would not work.

Put double quote between a single quote string like below.

```
replacements = {'"ArmReoriented", "visible": true' : '"ArmReoriented", "visible": false'}
```

Comment: Performing textual replacements on JSON data is not something we should ever be endorsing. It's innately unreliable -- for example, the JSON could be written without non-literal whitespace, thus not having spaces after the commas, in which case the replacement wouldn't work. Or it could have newlines everywhere instead of whitespaces -- still the same literal document, but a different encoding so attempts to recognize substrings will fail.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In my answer I'm not supporting the same as well. What I helped OP with is to create a dict of string key and values which has double quote in them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have upvoted the first comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to single quotes in your replacements dict:

```
replacements = {'"ArmReoriented", "visible": true': '"ArmReoriented", "visible": false,'}

data = 'asd asd asd "ArmReoriented", "visible": true asd asd'
for old, new in replacements.items():
    data = data.replace(old, new)
print(data)
```

You also may escape double quotes both from key and from value in your replacement dict:

```
replacements = {"\"ArmReoriented\", \"visible\": true": "\"ArmReoriented\", \"visible\": false,"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we know what key the value `ArmReoriented` is attached to, we can do this the *right* way, processing your content *structured data* rather than as a string:

```
import json, copy

def hideReorientedArm(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if obj.get("LastEvent") == "ArmReoriented" and obj.get("visible") is True:
            obj["visible"] = False
    return obj

def walk(obj, updateFn):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = [walk(elem, updateFn) for elem in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        obj = {k: walk(v, updateFn) for k, v in obj.items()}
    return updateFn(obj)

with open(mycodepath, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data = walk(data, hideReorientedArm)
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/Zr6546

---

Even if you *don't* know the name of the specific key having that value, you can still search all of them if that's necessary for some reason, replacing the shorter `hideReorientedArm` definition above with something more like the following:

```
def hideReorientedArm(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if obj.get("visible") is True:
            foundArmReoriented = False
            for (k,v) in obj.items():
                if v == "ArmReoriented":
                    foundArmReoriented = True
                    break
            if foundArmReoriented:
                obj["visible"] = False
    return obj
```

...see this version running at https://ideone.com/z34Mx1